# Google calendar event respond on behalf of guest

Tags: google-calendar-api

I scheduled an event on my Google Calendar and one of the guests called me asking me to mark them as a "maybe."

Is there a way for me to mark the RSVP on behalf of the guest on my event?

The only thing I found online that can do this is iGoogle and that was phased out in 2015.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to test the [**`Events: insert - attendees[].responseStatus`**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert):

> The attendee's response status. Possible values are:
>
> - "**needsAction**" - The attendee has not responded to the invitation.
> - "**declined**" - The attendee has declined the invitation.
> - "**tentative**" - The attendee has tentatively accepted the invitation.
> - "**accepted**" - The attendee has accepted the invitation.

I've tested the this and it let my guess have a pre-valued response (accepted) on his behalf. I've used "Try this API" on the same page of the document and checked my calendar if it works.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a chance you can give me an example on what I need to put into the "Try this API" section?